# How can I write a 2D array in python using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code and I want to assign a 2D array in python.

The algorithm for my code is

```
For i = 0 To n
                A(i, 0) = 0
            Next i
```

How can I convert the above code into python ?

If it was a 1d array then I could use

```
A = [0 for i in range(int(n))]
```

However, for the 2d array I am not getting any clue. I am using python 3.3.

Thanks for your attention.

Jdbaba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest them.

```
[[0 for i in ...] for j in ...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I used as per your suggestion like this : `A = [[0 for i in range(int(n))]for j in 0]`. I got the error "Type error 'int' is not iterable".

Comment: @Jdbaba `for j in 0` is the problematic part, 0 is an integer which is not iterable like lists, tuples, strings and dictionaries(and generators too), change that to something like `for j in range(number_of_rows)`